# What is the difference between [[call]] and [[construct]]?

Tags: javascript

When calling a constructor with new, it's not possible to directly use an array and apply (apply does a [[Call]] and not a [[Construct]]). However, an array can be easily used with new thanks to spread syntax.

```
var dateFields = [1970, 0, 1];  // 1 Jan 1970
var d = new Date(...dateFields);
```

So why we can't use apply for constructor?
Is there any difference between call and construct?

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear what the core of your problem is. Please, post code for both sides of the story. What do you mean by your constructor example?

Comment: Isn't there `Reflect.construct` ?

Comment: @JonasW. that's also ES6. Same problem.

Comment: What apply does is, it takes arguments list as an array and it passes them. Refer **[this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A constructor function accesses the constructed object with `this`, which you can easily mock with `apply`s first argument, so [[Construct]] is basically just a [[Call]] with a different context:

```
var obj = Object.create(Date.prototype);
Date.apply(obj, dateFields);
```

If you want an ES6 version, there is a quite new method to call [[construct]] directly:

```
var obj = Reflect.construct(Date, dateFields);
```

Answer (score 3):

[[Call]] is invoked via `Date(…)` whereas [[Construct]] is invoked via `new Date(…)`. If you were to attempt to [[Construct]] a `Date` via `new Date.apply(…, dateFields)`, it actually invokes [[Construct]] on the `Function.prototype.apply` method, not the `Date` object, which does not properly initialize a `Date` object, but rather it attempts to initialize an object with [[Prototype]] equal to `apply.prototype` which is `undefined` since `apply()` is not a constructable function, and therefore throws a `TypeError`.

To clarify, I'm not saying it's impossible to apply an array of arguments to a `Date` constructor in ES5, I'm just explaining why using `apply` to [[Construct]] a `Date` will not work.